# reusing jsp custom tags in multiple projects

Tags: java, jsp

does anybody know an elegant way how to reuse jsp custom tags in multiple projects?  The only thing that I can think of is creating a jar every time with the classes that extend custom tag, putting it into the multiple projects, and separately putting the .tld and jsp files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine several tags which are related to a specific topic (db, validation etc.) into one tag library for reuse in multiple projects. JSPs don't belong to a tag library.

See also [Tag Libraries tutorial](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tutorial/TagLibrariesTOC.html)

Comment: I understand that grouping custom tags by their functionality is a wise thing to do but that's not what I asked and also when I said about JSPs I mean custom tags that use JSP to generate html.  My question is is there an elegant way of reusing custom tags between multiple projects?  Suppose there's 2 custom tags, T1 and T2, and T1 uses a jsp bla.jsp.  Will I end up having to copy bla.jsp to every project everytime I make a change to it?

Comment: @SBel Sorry for the delay (1 year+) you would only need to copy the advanced functionality to other projects when you need the new tags in these projects. In case you use maven you could configure the build process to get dependend libraries from a (local) maven repository. I wouldn't recommend this practice unless reallyy required.